# How to set max number of threads running concurrently using ThreadPool in .NET

Tags: .net, queue, threadpool

I need to execute a fixed number of Threads,say 5, in parallel, and en-queue all the remaining Threads. Here is a piece of code I tried.

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(5, 0);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc), task1);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);//'ThreadProc' is the callback function
```

Now, when I'm trying to run, say 7 Threads in parallel then it is running all the Threads simultaneously instead of running 5 Thread and queuing next 2 Threads. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Parallel with For/ForEach then you have `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` which will limit the number of concurrent operations.

Comment: can you give a sample code with respect to the ThreadPool code??

Comment: you don't need the `ThreadPool` code anymore, with `Parallel` you can just process stuff on multiple threads, the difference is that `ForEach` is blocking compared to `QueueUserWorkItem`, that is why I asked if you can use it.